# How to integrate TestRail with Jenkins?

Tags: testing, jenkins, automated-tests, testrail

I am trying to integrate TestRail with Jenkins where I want to run some test cases from test rail which calls the test cases in jenkins, and then writes the result back to TestRail itself, or something similar to this.

I know there is an API for this, but so far I am not able to figure out how to go ahead with this API.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Jenkins plugin maintained by the Jenkins team at [GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/testrail-plugin):

> Integrate test results from Jenkins into TestRail. Upload your junit
>   test results to TestRail after every run.

The plugin only allows to populate TestRail with the test results, but maybe you can start from there.

Answer (score 1):

I too am attempting to integrate TestRail with our Jenkins installation. This blog post is pretty good: https://qxf2.com/blog/reporting-to-testrail-using-python/

You will need a way to map each Jenkins test to the appropriate TestRail test-case id, Ex: C123.

After the Jenkins run, reconcile the test results with the mapping and POST to the TestRail API with the test_run_id, test-case id, and the test result status_id as defined in TestRail.

Comment: I ended up writing a nose plugin that allows annotation of tests to generate a mapping file for use in reconciling results with TestRail test cases:

https://github.com/eventbrite/nose-annotator